# I'm having trouble with "AXIOS PATCH" method

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am trying to update my database record using "axios patch" method.

This is my code:

```
editClient(client) {
  let data = new FormData();
  data.append("name", this.client.name);
  data.append("email", this.client.email);
  data.append("phone", this.client.phone);
  data.append("_method", "PATCH");
  axios
    .post(`/api/clients/${client.id}`, data)
    .then(res => {
      resolve(res.data.client);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data));
},
```

I tried this code:

```
axios
    .patch(`/api/clients/${client.id}`, {
      name: this.client.name,
      phone: this.client.phone,
      email: this.client.email
    })
    .then(res => {
      resolve(res.data.client);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data));
```

But it also dosn't work.

The error i get is

> POST http://localhost:8000/api/clients/27 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
{message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown co…4 02:12:57"` = updated_at:"2019-05-24 02:12:57"})", exception: "Illuminate\Database\QueryException", file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\prs3\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php", line: 664, trace: Array(60)}
exception: "Illuminate\Database\QueryException"
file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\prs3\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php"
line: 664
message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name:"2011"' in 'where clause'
```

And when I tried this code:

```
axios
    .patch(`/api/clients/${client.id}`, {
      data: this.client
    })
    .then(res => {
      resolve(res.data.client);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data));
```

The error i get is

> app.js:285 PATCH http://localhost:8000/api/clients/27 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

```
{message: "The given data was invalid.", errors: {…}}
errors:
email: ["The email field is required."]
name: ["The name field is required."]
phone: ["The phone field is required."]
__proto__: Object
message: "The given data was invalid."
```

Im new in axios and vue. Im trying to learn on how to build and CRUD api using axios.

I tried to find other ways and i can't find any.

This is my controller:

```
public function update(Client $client) {
        $val = $client ? ','.$client : '';
        $client->update($this->_val($val));
        return back();
    }

    public function _val($val) {
        return request()->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'min:2', 'unique:clients,name'.$val],
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'unique:clients,email'.$val],
            'phone' => ['required', 'alpha_num'],
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: The request worked fine. It's just missing the data, so Laravel sent validation error as a response

Comment: when I'm using `data: this.client` it call for a Laravel validation error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your axios post code is fine. It's working fine. The error you get in the post field is `larvel error column not found`.

I guess you made a typo in some column name while saving data or you entered unknown column by mistake which is not in the table.

Please provide laravel side code, so we can see where you facing an error.
By the way from your question =>  Your `axios.post code` is correct

Comment: i updated my post with my controller. By the way my "axios.post" is fine.

Comment: i mean the create one. but the update method didn't work

Comment: `$this->_val($val)` return bolean i guess. It will return ethier true or false. `Unknown column 'name:"2011"' in 'where clause'` thats the error actually.

Comment: sorry my bad I put Die and Dump on my controller. BTW thanks it worked now